SQLAlchemy not returning timezone aware timestamp with TIMESTAMP(timezone=True)
I have the following Oracle table:
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle import TIMESTAMP
from sqlalchemy.sql import func


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Identity(), primary_key=True)
    last_modified = mapped_column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), default=func.now())

When I execute a select statement, I expect to get back a timezone-aware datetime object:
async def test_get_date(session: AsyncSession):
    foo = Foo()
    session.add(foo)
    await session.commit()

    stmt = select(Foo)
    row = (await session.execute(stmt)).scalar()

    assert row.last_modified.tzinfo is not None

But the test fails with the following error:
>       assert row.last_modified.tzinfo is not None
E       assert None is not None
E        +  where None = datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 26, 17, 14, 19, 851).tzinfo
E        +    where datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 26, 17, 14, 19, 851) = <arthur.database.models.Foo object at 0x10a174110>.last_modified

tests/test_db.py:58: AssertionError
====================================================================================== short test summary info =======================================================================================
FAILED tests/test_db.py::test_get_date - assert None is not None

Is there something I'm missing? Interestingly, when I set timezone=False and I pass in a timezone aware object, I do get a timezone aware object back when I query the database, but I would like to be able to get timezone aware objects back in cases where I let Oracle generate a default value.

Also asked on GitHub here.
